# Android: How to get a request url to upload a video to you tube?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have an app in which i need to upload a video to you tube from device. I need to send client id, developer id, request url, redirect url as parameters to upload a video to you tube. I got all the values ,but i am not able to get request url. How to get it? Can any one of you suggest a solution to this?

I followed the below url:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2

Comment: Did you ever find a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [YouTube APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Sending_a_Browser_Upload_API_Request)? It looks like they have support for uploading videos there.

Comment: Hi Alex,I have checked it but didn't find any way to get request url